# Collection in Backbone.js Not Firing Events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am trying to implement an action when a change to a model in a given collection is fired, but whenever I try to put a listener on the `change`, `add`, or `remove` events on my collection, no events are fired. When I attached a change event to a model's `initialize` function (just to test), the `change` event was fired successfully. The view below doesn't itself change the code, but I want it to re-render itself whenever a change to the collection has been made. It could be something wrong with my setup, but I want to get your advice. Below is my code:

**contact.js (Model):**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone){

  var ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/contacts'
    });

  return ContactModel;
});
```

**contacts.js (Collection):**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/contact'
], function($, _, Backbone, Contact){

  var ContactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/contacts',
    model: Contact
  });

  return ContactCollection;

});
```

**contactlist.js (View):**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/contactlist.html',
  'collections/contacts'
], function($, _, Backbone, contactListTemplate, Contacts){

  var ContactListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.contact-list',
    render: function(options) {
        var that = this;
        var contacts = new Contacts();
        contacts.on("add", function() {
            console.log('change');
        });
        contacts.fetch({
            success: function(contacts) {
                var results = contacts.models;
                if (options.query || options.query === '') {
                    var results = [];
                    var query = options.query.toUpperCase();
                    for (var contact in contacts.models) {
                        if (contacts.models[contact].get('firstname').toUpperCase().indexOf(query) !== -1 ||
                                contacts.models[contact].get('lastname').toUpperCase().indexOf(query) !== -1 ||
                                contacts.models[contact].get('email').toUpperCase().indexOf(query) !== -1 ||
                                contacts.models[contact].get('phonenumber').toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(query) !== -1)
                        {
                            results.push(contacts.models[contact]);
                        }
                    }
                    options.idclicked = null;
                }
                if (!options.idclicked && results[0]) {
                    options.idclicked = results[0].get('id');
                    Backbone.history.navigate('/contacts/' + results[0].get('id'), {trigger: true});
                }
                var template = _.template(contactListTemplate, {contacts: results, idclicked: options.idclicked});
                that.$el.html(template);
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.contact-list').scrollTop(options.scrolled);
                });
            }
        });
    },
    events: {
        'click .contact': 'clickContact'
    },
    clickContact: function (ev) {
        $('.contact-clicked').removeClass('contact-clicked').addClass('contact');
        $(ev.currentTarget).addClass('contact-clicked').removeClass('contact');
        window.location.replace($(ev.currentTarget).children('a').attr('href'));
    }
  });

  return ContactListView;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running `fetch()`, the collection will trigger it's `reset` event, not `add`.

```
contacts.on("reset", function() {
    console.log('reset');
});
```

That will run as soon as the fetch completes, before your `success` callback.

`change` runs when the model itself has attributes changed, which you don't do anywhere in the code you posted.

Also generally I wouldn't access `.models` directly. I'd do this:

```
var results = contacts.toArray();
if (options.query || options.query === ''){
  results = contacts.filter(function(contact){
    return _.any(['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phonenumber'], function(attr){
      return contact.get(attr).toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(query) !== -1;
    });
  }); 
// ...
```

#### Update

As it is now, you create the collection when you render. This is not a good idea because ideally you would want to be able to render again without fetching all of the data again.

I would move the collection creation logic into the view's `initialize` function like this:

```
initialize: function(options){
  this.collection = new Contacts();
  this.collection.on('reset add remove', this.render, this);
}
```

That way, as the collection changes, render is automatically triggered. This is complicated by your `options`, so I would try to change how you pass those arguments in. Maybe add a 'setOptions' function that saves the options to use while rendering. Ideally `render` will re-render the page identically to how it was before the call, it doesn't normally have arguments.

Comment: I tried to clarify what I want to achieve above by editing my question. The suggestion worked, but I'm not sure if it satisfies what I want to do. Should I provide any other information? Sorry if I'm bugging you.

Comment: @BradRoss Updated. Hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think it does. In regards to the comment about not fetching all the data again, what conceptually should I try to do when restructuring my app? Sorry to bother, but it's good to learn best practices before I form any bad habits.

Comment: @BradRoss One of the things that makes Backbone so popular is that is is extremely open, so a lot of things are just your call. I'd focus on keeping data and presentation separate, and try to not make things too asynchronous. So in my example, the rendering is a synchronous process based on an existing collection, it doesn't need to know anything about where that data came from or how it changes. Your previous code intertwined those two making it more complex.

Comment: I want to understand more about this and your comment about not fetching data every time you render, but I don't want to bother you more. Is there a tutorial/article/book I can read that would help me understand and implement this concept more?

Answer (score 9):

Since Backbone 1.0 ([change log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)), the answer to this question isn't 100% accurate anymore.

In Backbone 1.0+, you'll have to pass `{ reset: true }` into the `.fetch()` method if you want the `reset` event to fire. See below.

Calling `fetch` on a collection will now trigger a 3 different events:

---

```
collection.fetch(); //triggers the following events
```

1. `request`: Triggered before the ajax request is made
2. `add`: (multiple times) this event will be triggered multiple times as each item in
   the data is added to the collection.
3. `sync`: Triggered after data on the collection is synced with the
   data provider (data added to collection, ajax request completed)

---

To revert to the old style of backbone events, you need to call

```
collection.fetch({ reset: true }); //triggers the following events
```

1. `request`: Triggered before the ajax request is made
2. `reset`: Triggered when all data is placed into the collection.
3. `sync`: Triggered after data on the collection is synced with the
   data provider (data added to collection, ajax request completed)

---

The best way to quickly see what events that your collection *is triggering*, is to bind to the `all` event and log the arguments:

```
collection.on('all', function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```